# Solvting the simultaneous equations with cross terms.

Tags: polynomials

I have to solve the following simultaneous equation.

$x_d=A_1x^2+A_2x+A_3xy+A_4$

$y_d=B_1y^2+B_2y+B_3xy+B_4$

where $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,B_1,B_2,B_3$ and $B_4$ are constants.

How can I represent the $x$ and $y$ in terms of $x_d$ and $y_d$?

I have no idea because of the $xy$ term in the equations.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: From $(1)$ express $y$ as a function of $x$. Plug the result in $(2)$ to face a long polynomial in $x$. Solve it and recompute $y$

Comment: Geometrically, it is the intersection of 2 hyperbolas, one with one of the asymptotes the $x$ axis, the other the $y$ axis. This can give 4 points of intersection. How do you choose the good one ?